# How to use option from manual for netflow?

Tags: configuration

I want to filter the netflow records by `engine_id`, I have tried

```
nfdump -r <FILE> engine_id 10
```

and

```
nfdump -r <FILE> -s engine_id 10
```

But, it is not working.

What do I do wrong?

[Here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/nfdump.1.html) you find the manual for `nfdump`.

Comment: The man page has `engine-id` instead of `engine_id`. Try that, and also quote your filter on the command line, which means that the shell passes it to nfdump as a single parameters, instead of one per word. So try `nfdump -r "/path/to/file.ext" "engine-id 10"`

Comment: @GertvandenBerg Thanks for the reply. I issued command as you said `nfdump -r "nfcapd.201510262034" "engine-id 10"`, but im getting output like this `Date first seen          Duration Proto      Src IP Addr:Port          Dst IP Addr:Port   Packets    Bytes Flows
Summary: total flows: 0, total bytes: 0, total packets: 0, avg bps: 0, avg pps: 0, avg bpp: 0
Time window: 2015-10-26 20:34:49 - 2015-10-26 20:35:51
Total flows processed: 124, Blocks skipped: 0, Bytes read: 6744
Sys: 0.000s flows/second: 124124.1   Wall: 0.000s flows/second: 2530612.2 `. Not getting the records(That file has data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know we can filter with engine id in netflow records. I found this [LINK](http://blog.shin.do/2014/12/netflow-on-open-vswitch-2/). My goal is to differentiate the input OVS port in different servers. From that article, we can differentiate the input OVS ports with combination of `"add_to_interface=true”, “engine_id=10”`.

In that Article

*"There is another use case for Engine ID. As I already explained that OVS uses OpenFlow port number as an In/Out interface number in NetFlow flow record. Because OpenFlow port number is a per bridge unique number, there is a chance for these numbers to collide across bridges. To get around this problem, you can set “add_to_interface” to true."*

*“When this parameter is set to true, the 7 most significant bits of In/Out interface number is replaced with the 7 least significant bits of Engine ID. This will help interface number collision happen less likely.”*